# bootstrap 4 modal bug?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tether

```
  <html><body><div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">Hello Modal</div></div></div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script> function showModal { $('#myModal').modal('show') }</script>
  </body></html>
```

When calling showModal:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your bootstrap.css file???

Comment: that is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

your code should look like this

```
 <script> function showModal() { $('#myModal').modal('show'); };</script>
```

this should be ok